# JUnit to test for StringBuffers

Tags: java, methods, junit, stringbuffer

**Assignment:** Write a JUnit test assuming you have two StringBuffer references named sbOne and sbTwo and you only want it to pass if the two references point to the same StringBuffer object.

I want to make sure this actually a good way to approach this assignment. I wrote the assumed method for practice:

```
package StringBufferJUni;

public class StringBufferUni {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }

    public boolean StringBuff(StringBuffer sbOne, StringBuffer sbTwo){
        sbTwo = sbOne;
        if(sbTwo==sbOne){
            return true;
        }

        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my JUnit test:

```
package StringBufferJUni;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnitStringBuffer {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        StringBuffer sbOne = new StringBuffer("hello");
        StringBuffer sbTwo = new StringBuffer("hello");
        StringBufferUni stBuffer = new StringBufferUni();
        boolean hel = stBuffer.StringBuff(sbOne, sbTwo);
        assertEquals(true, hel);
    }

}
```

Is this actually passing due to the references pointing to the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
sbTwo = sbOne;
```

is setting one object *reference* to the value of another.

This line:

```
if( sbTwo==sbOne )
```

is comparing to see if the two *references* are equal, which will always be true because of the above line.

It's not comparing anything about the object itself (ie: it's *not* the same as `sbOne.equals(sbTwo)`)

If you want to tell if the references point to the same object, then you need to simply use:

```
if (sbTwo==sbOne)
```

and remove the line: `sbTwo=sbOne`

For further consideration, this test illustrates what you are doing:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("hello");
    StringBuffer sb2 = sb1;

    assertTrue(sb1 == sb2);  // this will pass, same object reference

    sb2 = new StringBuffer("hello");  // create a new object

    assertFalse(sb1 == sb2);  // this will be false, since the objects may be equal, but the references are not.
}
```

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Thanks for that perspective.