# JUnit different behaviour seen between String and StringBuffer

Tags: java, junit

I was writing a JUnit test case to compare two StringBuffers. (The test will check for string reversal.)

```
@Test
public void testReverseString() {
    StringBuffer orig = new StringBuffer("fedcba");
    StringBuffer exp  = new StringBuffer("abcdef");
    // function will reverse the string so 
    // orig will be "abcdef" after the call
    Question1_2.reverseString(orig);        
    //System.out.println(exp + " " + orig); // output - abcdef abcdef
    //assertEquals(exp.toString(), orig.toString()); This Passes
    //assertEquals(exp, orig);                       This FAILS
    //assertTrue(exp.equals(orig));                  This FAILS
}
```

As per this [JUnit to test for StringBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494332/junit-to-test-for-stringbuffers)  assertEquals(exp, orig); should work.

```
assertEquals(exp.toString(), orig.toString()); This Passes
//assertEquals(exp, orig);                       This FAILS
//assertTrue(exp.equals(orig));                  This FAILS
```

I am not sure if I have misunderstood some basic stuff wrt String, StringBuffer and JUnit assertEquals.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: `Question1_2.reverseString(orig) ` what is `Question1_2` this ?? in the program??

Comment: Question1_2.reverseString(orig) - it is my class that is used to reverse the string.. it only conatins logic to reverse the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringBuffer` does NOT override `equals()` method. So, it uses the implementation of `Object` class which checks for the reference equality (Checks if both the objects are the **same**).

In your case, both the objects are obviously not the same (though their contents are the same), hence it fails.

`String` on the other hand overrides the `equals()` method and returns `true` if the contents of both the Strings are the same.

Comment: Thanks it explains the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is so simple  in First Expression

(i) `assertEquals(exp.toString(), orig.toString());` Passing `String` Object  as argument. assertEquals is overloaded with `String` Class. So, It will accept it as a `String` and checks the value equality. SO, this will Pass the test.

(ii) `assertTrue(exp, orig);` Here  you are passing `StringBuffer` Object as an argument  assertEquals is not overloaded with `StringBuffer` Class. So, It will accept it as a `Object` and checks the reference equality not the value. SO, this will raise an Exception during test.

(iii) `assertEquals(exp.equals(orig));` Here  you are using `equals` method which actually belongs to Object Class not to `StringBuffer`. . so, Again it will checks the reference equality not the value. SO, this will fail the test coz both object referring to different `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

assertEquals(exp, orig);  is basically comparing the reference of the two objects. As you know that in memory both the objects are separately created with unique reference id and that's the reason test case is failing.

See following code and its output:

```
@Test
    public void equal()
    {
        TestClass obj1= new TestClass();
        TestClass obj2= new TestClass();
        Assert.assertEquals(obj1,obj2);
    }
```

Following is the output in which you can cleary see the expected and actual result which is a memory reference.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :com.company.TestClass@6c20cbef
Actual   :com.company.TestClass@5d2cef5e
```

Now if I assign obj1 to obj2 then both object references point to the same object; see below example which will pass the test case.

```
@Test
    public void equal()
    {
        TestClass obj1= new TestClass();
        TestClass obj2;
        obj2= obj1;
        Assert.assertEquals(obj1,obj2);
    }
```